# With Express, res.send(data), the browser download the data as a file instead of showing it as HTML webpage

Tags: node.js, express

```
    var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var fs = require("fs");
    var path = require("path");
    app.use('/node_modules', express.static('node_modules'));
    app.get("/", function (req,res) {
        pathname = path.join(__dirname,"index.html");
        fs.readFile(pathname,function (err,data) {
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
                res.send(data);
// the res.send(data), the webpage receive the data, and download it instead of showing it as HTML webpage.
            }
        )
    });
    app.listen("3000",function () {
        console.log("express server constructed");
    })
```

Comment: You should set the content header to text/html, then the browser will know that it can render the file as html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will tell you the approachs to do

```
fs.readFile(pathname,function (err,data) {
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
            }
```

If you don't want readFile you can use this.

```
res.sendfile(pathname);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
res.sendFile(pathname);
```

instead of

```
res.send(data);
```